# Excel graph using c#

Tags: c#, excel

I have a quick question. I have this c# program that i want to store data into an excel chart. So far i have managed to store the values into five different columns. Each column stands for one kind of calculation: time acceleration velocity force distance (in that order). I want to create an excel time-distance chart using c#. I have no idea where to start. Here is my excel creator method:
Any help will be greatly appreciated. 
Thank you.

```
 public void exportResults()
        {
            Excel.Application xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

            if (xlApp == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Excel is not properly installed!!");
                return;
            }


            Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
            Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
            object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

            xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
            xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
            int i;
            int j;
            for (j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            {
                xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1] = "Time";
                xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 2] = "Acceleration";
                xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 3] = "Velocity";
                xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 4] = "Force";
                xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 5] = "Distance";
            }
            // set each cell
            for(i = 0; i <= 30; i++){
                for (j = 0; j < 5; j++)
                {
                    xlWorkSheet.Cells[i+2, j+1] = data[i, j];
                }
            }

            xlWorkBook.SaveAs(/*"c:\\csharp-Excel.xls"*/ Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
            xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
            xlApp.Quit();

            releaseObject(xlWorkSheet);
            releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
            releaseObject(xlApp);


            Console.WriteLine("Excel file created , you can find it in the directory you stored it: {0}", Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following after creating your cells.

```
// Add a using statement
// using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
Excel.Range chartRange;
Excel.ChartObjects xlCharts = (Excel.ChartObjects)xlWorkSheet.ChartObjects(Type.Missing);
Excel.ChartObject myChart = (Excel.ChartObject)xlCharts.Add(10, 80, 300, 250);

Excel.Chart chartPage = myChart.Chart;
chartRange = xlWorkSheet.get_Range("A1", "C12"); // your data grid range

chartPage.SetSourceData(chartRange, misValue); 
chartPage.ChartType = Excel.XlChartType.xlConeCol;//xlCylinderCol;//xlLine;//xlColumnClustered;

//export chart as picture file

chartPage.Export(@"H:\img\excel_chart_export.png", "PNG", misValue);
```

You can change the type of chart at the line stating.

> chartPage.ChartType = Excel.XlChartType